# Octave - array to number

Tags: arrays, numbers, octave

I have an array `a=[0 1 0 1 1 0]` and I would like to turn the content of that array into a number ( `a=010110` ). How do I do that?

And I would also like to to the opposite:
 if I have a number `b=100101`, I would like to get an array `a=[1 0 0 1 0 1]`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but go from Matrix to number:

```
a = [1 0 1 1 0 1];
a = mat2str(a);                                % returns '[1,0,1,1,0,1]'
a = strrep(substr(a, 2, numel(a)-2), ',', ''); % remove ','  ,  '['  ,  ']'
a = str2num(a);                                % convert to number
```

Number to matrix:

```
a = 110011001;
a = num2str(a, 1000000)-'0';
```

Where `1000000` is the precision Octave is using when converting the number to a string. This needs to be large enough to accommodate the numbers your are converting.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very weird thing that you're trying to do, most likely there's a better way to do that. What's exactly your problem? What are you trying to do that requires you to convert a vector into a string?

And to answer your question, you can convert a vector of numbers, with `sprintf`. The following will work fine for integers (see [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) documentation for details on how to deal with others).

```
octave> a = [ 0 1 0 1 0 0]
a =

   0   1   0   1   0   0

octave> sprintf ("%i", a)
ans = 010100
```